# Could not remove key value from associative array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove the key value from one associative array using PHP but it could not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$resultArr=array(array("stars"=>"3","starcount"=>3),array("stars"=>"4","starcount"=>4),array("stars"=>"5","starcount"=>5));
foreach ($resultArr as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists("stars", $value)) {
        unset($value['stars']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($resultArr);
?>
```

Here I need to remove all `stars` key and its value from json array but my code is not working as expected.

Comment: in this case you just unset the `$value['stars']` which is not refer to the original array. Look at the shubham715's answer for a better unset usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$resultArr=array(array("stars"=>"3","starcount"=>3),array("stars"=>"4","starcount"=>4),array("stars"=>"5","starcount"=>5));
foreach ($resultArr as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists("stars", $value)) {
        unset($resultArr[$key]['stars']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($resultArr);
```

**Explaination**

You should unset key from $resultArr array by using $key

Answer (score 0):

To separate Key and Value:

```
foreach ($resultArr as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
 echo $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach statement copies value and it means $value variable has a copy of element instead original element. 
You can use access by key to direct access to element of array, for example:

```
foreach ($resultArr as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists("stars", $value)) {
        unset($resultArr[$key]['stars']);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

```
foreach ($resultArr as $key => &$value) {
    if (array_key_exists("stars", $value)) {
        unset($value['stars']);
    }
}
```